# URL Parameter to XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, url-parameters

Is there a possibility to convert the URL Paramter to a XML.

Example, I have a String with the URL-Parmeter:

```
"firsteName=John&lastName=Doe&birthDate=1970-01-01&..."
```

Now I want to convert the String to a XML like:

```
<root>
   <firstName>John</firstName>
   <lastName>Doe</lastName>
   <birthDate>1970-01-01</birthDate>
   ...
</root>
```

I tried to tokenize the string with XPath, but the result is not the expacted.

The input String is in the follow XML:

```
<Response>
   <query> 
    firsteName=John&amp;lastName=Doe&amp;birthDate=1970-01-01    
   </query>
</Response>
```

And i tried the following XPath on the XML:

```
fn:tokenize(/Response/query/, '&')
```

Is there a way to do this, with xslt or xpath?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code you have already tried? Thank you.

Comment: it's easy when you are in Linux OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tokenizing with current XPath is easy:

```
tokenize($querystring,'&amp;')
```

produces a sequence of strings, from each of which name and value can be extracted with `substring-before($avs,'=')` and `substring-after($avs,'=').

Constructing the elements you wish to return requires something more powerful than XPath.  In XQuery, given that `$querystring` contains the string you want to parse, the following will return the `root` element you want:

```
return element root {
  for $avs in tokenize($querystring,'&amp;')
  return for $name in substring-before($avs,'=') 
         return for $val in substring-after($avs,'=')
                return element { $name } { $val }
}
```

Here the element constructor is the only thing that is not pure XPath 3.0.

In XSLT (2.0 or 3.0),

```
<xsl:element name="root">
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize($querystring,'&amp;')">
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="substring-before(.,'=')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="value" select="substring-after(.,'=')"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
```

Both the XQuery and the XSLT produce

```
<root>
  <firsteName>John</firsteName>
  <lastName>Doe</lastName>
  <birthDate>1970-01-01</birthDate>
</root>
```

which differs from the sample output you said you want in not correcting the misspelling of 'firstName' in the query string.  I will leave such refinements as spelling correction of parameter names as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Michael: Is there a reason you nest the FLWOR expressions, rather than using `let` for `$name` and `$val`? Pardon the formatting, but: 
`for $avs in tokenize($querystring,'&amp;')
let $name := substring-before($avs,'=') 
let $val := substring-after($avs,'=')
return element { $name } { $val }`

Comment: @joewiz:  I was trying to stay within XPath as long as I could, so that I could say that the only non-XPath construct in the expression was the element constructor.  (So: no, no important or interesting reason.)